# How do i replicate a = b and c = d logic over multiple values of a crystal reports parameter?

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I'm trying to recreate a sql query into a crystal report with parameters than the user can use to specify which items should show up on a report. My current sql query is as follows:

```
select *
from SALES
where (customerID = '4' and date = '5/2/2019)
or    (customerID = '6' and date = '4/30/2019')
or    (customerID = '69' and date = '8/18/1984')
```

...etc.

I want to be able to replicate this in crystal reports and allow the user to put in customer ID and date pairs and pull any records that match. The user will not always have a set number of customer/date pairs when running the report so i am trying to keep it open as possible

ive tried to switch the parameters to allow multiple values but that produces more results than expected because it will return every row for a given customer as long as they had sales on any of the dates listed, not just the one they are paired with. i also tried creating a supressed field that is the concatenated id and date and then concatenating the parameters to see which ones match, however it gives an error when i input more than one pair regarding the array

Comment: what are the values you are passing and if there is none what are the defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Begin with a report that shows all sales regardless of customerID or date.

Create 2 parameter fields in your crystal report.  The first will be named "customerID" and the second will be named "date".

Parameter Fields can be setup to allow a single value to be entered, or they can be setup to allow multiple values to be selected from a list or a range of values to be selected by entering a min and max value.

The go into Select Expert and create 2 fields that will be filtered when records are selected by the report.  The 2 fields to be filtered will be "cusotmerID" and "date".  Each field should be setup so that the values entered in your parameter fields are compared against the values in the data set selected by your report and only the records that have the customerID and date values input into the parameters are not filtered out of the data set.

The formula in Select Expert should look similar to the following, but it can vary a little depending upon how you setup your parameter fields and select expert filters:

```
{SALES.cusotmerID} in {?customerID} and
{SALES.date} in {?date}
```

Comment: sorry but this will not work because if the user enters multiple values and one customers date matches another customers date, it will pull too many rows. for example: customer id 1234, date 1/1/2018. customer id 5678, date 4/15/1994. if customer 1234 happens to also have a sale in the table on 4/15/1994 it will pull that sale even though i only want it to pull the id/date pairs that the user requested